# The prime ant 

Tags: code-golf, sequence, primes

The "prime ant" is an obstinate animal that navigates the integers and divides them until there are only primes left!

---

Initially, we have an infinite array A containing all the integers >= 2 : `[2,3,4,5,6,.. ]`

Let `p` be the position of the ant on the array. Initially, `p = 0` (array is 0-indexed)

Each turn, the ant will move as follows:

- if `A[p]` is prime, the ant moves to the next position : `p ← p+1`
- else, if `A[p]` is a composite number, let `q` be its smaller divisor > 1. We divide `A[p]` by `q`, and we add `q` to `A[p-1]`. The ant moves to the previous position: `p ← p-1`

Here are the first moves for the ant:

```
 2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  ... 
 ^
 2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  ... 
    ^
 2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  ... 
       ^
 2  5  2  5  6  7  8  9  ... 
    ^
 2  5  2  5  6  7  8  9  ... 
       ^
 2  5  2  5  6  7  8  9  ... 
          ^
 2  5  2  5  6  7  8  9  ... 
             ^
 2  5  2  7  3  7  8  9  ... 
          ^
```

Your program should output the ant's position after `n` moves. (you can assume `n <= 10000`)

Test cases:

```
0 => 0
10 => 6
47 => 9
4734 => 274
10000 => 512
```

**Edit.** you can also use 1-indexed lists, it's acceptable to display the results 1, 7, 10, 275, 513 for the above test case.

This is code-golf, so the code with the shortest code in bytes wins.

Comment: I honestly thought there was an ant on my screen when I saw this in the Hot Network Questions.

Comment: I wonder whether the sequence is well-defined for arbitrarily large `n` (or whether the composite case could ever push the ant to the left of the initial `2`).

Comment: Can we use 1-indexing for the array instead?

Comment: @Tom Yes, no problem, as long as your program returns the correct results.

Comment: @SuperChafouin so outputs of for the test cases can be: `1,7,10,275,513` if 1-indexing stated? Or would they still need to match your outputs.

Comment: @SuperChafouin if we're using 1indexed array, is a 1-indexed result "correct"?

Comment: It's OK for me. I edit the question to allow 0-indexation or 1-indexation.

Comment: @MartinEnder Another open question is whether a prime > 7 can eventually be left behind for good.

Comment: @Arnauld I'm curious how the ant's position grows with respect to the number of moves.  My guess is logarithmic.

Comment: @kamoroso94 It's probably somehow related to [ω(n)](http://oeis.org/wiki/Number_of_distinct_prime_factors_of_n) and/or [Ω(n)](http://oeis.org/wiki/Omega(n),_number_of_prime_factors_of_n_(with_multiplicity)). If _p_ is the position and _n_ is the number of moves, then _p_ seems to be in the order of magnitude of _n.log(n)/log(log(n))_. But that's a complete guess...

Comment: I have the Android widget for stack exchange...I thought there was a bug on my screen.

Comment: @Arnauld Yeah, we can conjecture that for any given position `P≥0` there is an `N≥0` (depending on `P`) such that if the number `n` of moves is greater than `N`, then the position `f(n)` of the ant will always be greater than `P`, and the array entries with indices small than `P` will all be one-digit prime numbers (i.e. belong to `{ 2, 3, 5, 7 }`).

Comment: Looks oddly related to [this mathematical sequence](http://oeis.org/A059261), wonder whether we could alter the projection to stop it diverging later on in the sequence:
`M(0)=0; M(n+1)=M(n).f(M(n), n).f(M(n), n+1).d(M(n), n); -f(m, n)`

Comment: @KodosJohnson, gotta love outdoor computing!

Comment: @Arnauld Out as far as move n = 1,000,000,000 (where p = 17156661), the relationship between n and p is very close to p = n/(ln(n)*ln(ln(n))) .

Comment: I added this sequence to the On-Line Encylopedia of Integer Sequences as sequence [A293689](https://oeis.org/A293689). The graph is worth looking at.

Answer (score 10):

## [Alice](https://github.com/m-ender/alice), 45 bytes

```
/o
\i@/.&wqh!]k.&[&w;;?c]dt.n$k&;[.?~:![?+!kq
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8zJTE79/18/nysm00FfT628MEMxNltPLVqt3NraPjk2pUQvTyVbzTpaz77OSjHaXlsxu/D/f0MDIAAA)

Mostly straightforward implementation.

Looping `n` times in Alice is typically done by pushing a return address `n-1` times, then returning at the end of each iteration with `k`.  The last time through the loop, the `k` instruction has nowhere to return to, and execution proceeds forward.

This program uses the same `k` instruction to stop early when the number is prime.  As a result, the final iteration will always move the ant left.  To compensate for this bug, we do `n+1` iterations on a 1-indexed array, which gives exactly the result we want (and gives the case `n=0` for free).

Answer (score 7):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), <s>109 103 101</s> 94 bytes

```matlab
function i=a(n)i=1;for l=z=2:n+1
if nnz(q=factor(z(i)))>1
z(i--)/=p=q(1);z(i--)+=p;end
i++;end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY5Bq8IwEITv/RVzkSYUlaogWOL9XXwX/0BINhiIu9qmPu2f74uIh2X3G2aZEZftg@Y5jOxyFEY0VrGOpu2C9EhmMpsDN20VA5gndTfBuiy9mlTUWh/bqhzLpV6bm7mrVncfbMytI/ZVbJr3nst0sGq33@40FifJdEBdxBpxgHB6gYk8ebxDzz@/sAOceCqckvwNK5ykv9pUjC8Za4@htEa@FMO3ePmwCDERLHvQk9yYaTX/Aw)

This code will output the position in 1-indexing, so outputs for test cases are:

```matlab
0 => 1
10 => 7
47 => 10
4734 => 275
10000 => 513
```

---

This version uses some Octave optimisations so isn't compatible with MATLAB. The code below is a MATLAB compatible version.

---

## MATLAB, <s>130 123 118</s> 117 bytes

```matlab
function i=a(n)
z=2:n+1;i=1;for l=z
q=factor(z(i));if nnz(q)>1
z(i)=z(i)/q(1);i=i-1;z(i)=z(i)+q(1);else
i=i+1;end
end
```

Uses 1-indexing as with the Octave version. I've tested it against all test cases in MATLAB. As an example the output at 100000 is 3675 (one-indexing).

An commented version of the above code:

```matlab
function i=a(n)
    z=2:n+1;                %Create our field of numbers
    i=1;                    %Start of at index of 1 (MATLAB uses 1-indexing)
    for l=1:n               %For the required number of iterations
        q=factor(z(i));     %Calculate the prime factors of the current element
        if nnz(q)>1         %If there are more than one, then not prime
            z(i)=z(i)/q(1); %So divide current by the minimum
            i=i-1;          %Move back a step
            z(i)=z(i)+q(1); %And add on the minimum to the previous.
        else
            i=i+1;          %Otherwise we move to the next step
        end
    end
```

---

As a matter of interest, this is the ants positions vs number of iterations for the first 10000 values of n.

[image: Ant Position]

Seems likely that the Ant will probably tend to infinity, but who knows, looks can be deceiving.

---

- MATLAB: Saved 6 bytes with `for` instead of `while` and removing brackets from `if` - Thanks @Giuseppe
- MATLAB: Save 2 bytes - Thanks @Sanchises
- Octave: Save 10 bytes by using Octave `\=` and `+=` operations - Thanks @Giuseppe
- Octave: Save 2 bytes with `i++` and `i--` - Thanks @LuisMendo
- Octave: Save 7 bytes - Thanks @Sanchises

Comment: To get it to work on TIO, I think you need an `end` to match the function signature

Comment: @Giuseppe Ah, ok. In MATLAB the trailing `end` is optional.

Comment: you can make anonymous function by using @(n) at the start instead of using function i=a(n)

Comment: @Michthan can't do that in MATLAB. I don't think it is possible in Octave either as it has loops?

Comment: The trailing `end` is optional in Octave too. Here it is only needed because you have code after the function

Comment: @TomCarpenter https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.0.3/Anonymous-Functions.html#Anonymous-Functions That's where I found my information about anonymous functions;

Comment: In Octave we get `+=`, `-=`, `/=` so this is much shorter in Octave but then it won't work in MATLAB. But `if(nnz(q)>1)` should be `if nnz(q)>1` for -1 byte.

Comment: @Giuseppe cool, should of spotted those brackets. I like learning new optimisations like the += etc, don't know why MATLAB doesn't have them. Saved a couple more as well by using `for l=z` instead of `for l=1:n`.

Comment: @LuisMendo that's what I did as well (put the end in the footer on TIO).

Comment: Actually, I got it down to 91 bytes: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY7BasMwEETv@Yq5FEsYJ7gNFGLUey7JJT8gpBUVqLuOJaeNf95RCD3MYYY3zIgr9kbrGmZ2JQojGqtYB5mQzGLeD9yqaHodA5gXdTXBuiKTWlRsW631V79ZVNdFvTOjuapeDy/bmnEg9puqtWqAVfvPj73G20kKHdDUsEHMEE53MJEnj@fq5XiGzXDiqfqU5DdvcZLpx6YK3mVuPHK9jPJdgf/XtWERYiJY9qA/cnOh7foA "Octave – Try It Online"). Do you mind if I post this as my own answer? (the algorithm is the same, but the implementation is quite different)

Comment: @Sanchises might as well at this point, lol.

Comment: Actually, I don't feel like making a whole answer with explanation, so you may post my 90 bytes version, [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NU7bCsIwFPuVvMhaxpSpICj9AF/0xR8o7SkW6jm6dV7287NDfAghISERl@2TpikM7HIURjRWsQ7SIZnRrPdcq2haHQPahnlUDxOsy9KpUcW61lqPqmmiXpm7eahWH36yNvcDsZ8xzQyrtrvNVmNxkkx7VMWsEHsIpw@YyJPHPHo5nmF7OPFUdEry6pc4SXezqQQ/MlQefXmMfC2B/@nSsAgxESx70JvckGk5fQE "Octave – Try It Online"), if you like :)

Answer (score 7):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 120 bytes

```python
p=0
A=range(2,input()+2)
for _ in A:
 for q in range(2,A[p]):
	if A[p]%q<1:A[p]/=q;p-=1;A[p]+=q;break
 else:p+=1
print p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NcpBCsIwEEDRtXOK2QgNsWiCIKTOIucQkQqpBst0ksaFp49m4e4/@PIpz4VtrUIH8JRHfoTO7iLLu3RKWwXTkvGGkdE7wIbU8B/9Ra7KwSZO2HKbzsa12FMapCczNOgf7jmML8Awr8GJJgOSIxeUWo@nLw)

Ah, the rare `for`–`else` loop! The `else` clause only executes if the `for` body is *not* exited via `break`. In our case, this means we checked all `q`s and found none of them to divide `p`.

Answer (score 6):

## JavaScript (ES6), 91 bytes

```js
f=(n,a=[p=0])=>n--?f(n,a,(P=n=>++x<n?n%x?P(n):a[a[p]/=x,--p]+=x:p++)(a[p]=a[p]||p+2,x=1)):p
```

#### Demo

*NB: You may have to increase the default stack size of your engine to have it pass all test cases.*

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bcixCsIwEADQ3f8QciTRVgtC8Npf6F4yhNpItV6ORiRC/z3SUXR5w7u5l4v9PPJTRx4vw/wIdB/eOXsUpBx2jIUFrEnrxq@jRIuEtZTpTA1tU9MKAuM617HdY1Jas5WYDEsJYk1cWRaWB5WwBDCc@0AxTMNuClfhRQGw@Z7yt6rTnzpWAPkD)

Answer (score 6):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>108</s> <s>106</s> 94 bytes

```hs
([0]#[2..]!!)
(a:b)#(p:q)=length b:([b#(a+d:div p d:q)|d<-[2..p-1],mod p d<1]++[(p:a:b)#q])!!0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HUzLDoIwELz3K5bgoQRKWkSJBPyR2kOhvCJgEeJF/XVry2STmd2dmV6u92YcTVveDOZU@DyJY@F5AcIyrwIf63wJyrGZu62HKse88rEMVa6GF2hQ9vlRBXEhTZiIpody54KJMOQ2u3csIvA8aiY5zFCCfg7zBgeYpIYWOI0YjdLMzjG10kKgN0EUyitQxHY@ozRzfEHO5VSSpWg3u@XEEkS@5le3o@xWQ2qt/w) Example usage: `([0]#[2..]!!) 10` yields `6` (0-indexed).

The function `#` operates on two list, the reversed front of the array `[p-1, p-2, ..., 1]` and the infinite rest of the array `[p, p+1, p+2, ...]`. It constructs an infinite list of positions, from which the `n`th position is returned given an input `n`.

The pattern `((a:b)#(p:q))` binds `p` to the value of the current position of the ant and `a` to the value a the previous position. `b` is the prefix of the array from position 1 to `p-2` and `q` the infinite rest starting from position `p+1`.

We construct a list of recursive calls in the following way: We look at each divisor `d` of `p` (which is larger than one and smaller than `p`) in ascending order and add `b#(a+d:div p d:q)` for each of them, that is the current value `p` is divided by `d` and the ant moves one step to the left where `d` is added to `a`. Then we append `(p:a:b)#q` to the end of this list, which indicates the ant moving one step to the right.

We then take the first of those recursive calls from the list and prepend the current position, which coincides with the length of the prefix list `b`. Because the divisors are in ascending order, picking the first from the list of recursive calls ensures we use the smallest one. Additionally, because `(p:a:b)#q` is added to the end of the list, it is only selected if there are no divisors and `p` is thus prime.

*Edits:*
-2 bytes by switching the list of functions from descending to ascending order.
-12 bytes thanks to Zgarb's idea to index into an infinite list instead handling a counter, and by switching to 0-indexing.

Comment: [96 bytes](https://tio.run/##HU3LDoMgELzzFWvsAaMY8BESo/0RywHFV6oWq@ml7a@XgptNdmZ3ZmeU@72bZ9NXN4NrGlHh10kcC88LEJZFE/hYF1tQzd06HCM0Ba4bH8tQFWp6gQZljx9VEmfShIloeSi3LpkIw9p6zx@bCDyPmkVOK1Sgn9N6wAUWqaEHG8polHHbaWahLYHeBFGorsAQOydHGT85RU7mYMJzdKodyVmKyNf82n6Ww25Iq/Uf) by building an infinite list and indexing, instead of carrying around the counter.

Comment: @Zgarb Thanks a lot! It's even only 94 bytes when switching to 0-indexing.

Answer (score 5):

## TI-BASIC, <s>108</s> <s>103</s> <s>102</s> 98 bytes

Input and output are stored in `Ans`.  Output is 1-indexed.

```
Ans→N
seq(X,X,2,9³→A
1→P
For(I,1,N
1→X:∟A(P→V
For(F,2,√(V
If X and not(fPart(V/F:Then
DelVar XV/F→∟A(P
P-1→P
F+∟A(P→∟A(P
End
End
P+X→P
End
```

Comment: You can take a byte off of `fPart(∟A(P)/F:` with `fPart(F¹∟A(P:`. Same thing in the next line.

Comment: @ScottMilner That doesn't always work.  `not(fPart(7⁻¹7` is 0 but `not(fPart(7/7` is 1.

Answer (score 5):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 41 bytes

```
:Q1y"XHyw)Zp?5MQ}1MtYf1)/H(8MyfHq=*+9M]]&
```

Output is 1-based. The program times out for the last test case in the online interpreter.

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/3yrQsFIpwqOyXDOqwN7UN7DW0LckMs1QU99Dw8K3Ms2j0FZL29I3Nlbt/38Tc2MTAA)

#### Explanation

The program applies the procedure as described in the challenge. To do so, it makes unusually heavy use of MATL's manual and automatic clipboards.

The smallest divisor is obtained as the first entry in the prime factor decomposition.

The "divide" update is done by overwriting the corresponding entry of array *A*. The "add" update is done by element-wise adding to *A* an array that contains zeros except at the desired position.

```
:Q        % Implicitly input n. Push array [2 3 ... n+1]. This is the initial array A. 
          % It contains all required positions. Some values will be overwritten
1         % Push 1. This is the initial value for p
y         % Duplicate from below
"         % For each loop. This executes the following n times.
          %   STACK (contents whosn bottom to top): A, p
  XH      %   Copy p into clipboard H
  y       %   Duplicate from below. STACK: A, p, A
  w       %   Swap. STACK: A, A, p
  )       %   Reference indexing. STACK: A, A[p]
  Zp      %   Isprime. STACK: A, false/true
  ?       %   If true (that is, if A[p] is prime)
    5M    %     Push p from automatic clipboard. STACK: A, p
    Q     %     Add 1. STACK: A, p+1
  }       %   Else (that is, if A[p] is not prime)
    1M    %     Push A[p] from automatic clipboard. STACK: A, A[p]
    t     %     Duplicate. STACK: A, A[p], A[p]
    Yf    %     Prime factors, with repetitions. STACK: A, A[p], prime factors of A[p]
    1)    %     Get first element, d. STACK: A, A[p], d
    /     %     Divide. STACK: A, A[p]/d
    H     %     Push p from clipboard H. STACK: A, A[p]/d, p
    (     %     Assignment indexing: write value. STACK: A with A[p] updated
    8M    %     Push d from automatic clipboard.
    y     %     Duplicate from below. STACK: A with A[p] updated, d, A with A[p] updated
    f     %     Find: push indices of nonzero entries.
          %     STACK: A with A[p] updated, d, [1 2 ... n]
    Hq    %     Push p from clipboard H, subtract 1.
          %     STACK: A with A[p] updated, d, [1 2 ... n], p-1
    =     %     Test for equality, element-wise.
          %     STACK: A with A[p] updated, d, [0 ... 0 1 0 ... 0]
    *     %     Multiply, element-wise. STACK: A with A[p] updated, [0 ... 0 d 0 ... 0]
    +     %     Add, element-wise. STACK: A with A[p-1] and A[p] updated
    9M    %     Push p-1 from automatic clipboard.
          %     STACK: A with A[p-1] and A[p] updated, p-1
  ]       %   End if. The stack contains the updated array and index
]         % End for each. Process the next iteration
&         % Specify that the following implicit display function should display only
          % the top of the stack. Implicitly display
```

Answer (score 3):

## PARI/GP, 87 bytes

```
f(n)=A=[2..9^5];p=1;for(i=1,n,q=factor(A[p])[1,1];if(A[p]-q,A[p]/=q;p--;A[p]+=q,p++));p
```

Pretty self-explanatory (not so golf-ish). If you do not count the `f(n)=` part, that is 82 bytes. You can also start by `n->` (85 bytes).

It is a 1-indexed language.

---

**Edit:** The modification `illustrate(n,m)=A=[2..m+1];p=1;for(i=1,n,for(j=1,m,printf("%5s",if(j==p,Str(">",A[j],"<"),Str(A[j]," "))));print();q=factor(A[p])[1,1];if(A[p]!=q,A[p]/=q;p--;A[p]+=q,p++))` will print an illustration of the ant's walk (given a wide enough terminal). For example `illustrate(150,25)` will give the first 150 steps on 25 columns, like this:

```
  >2<   3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26
   2   >3<   4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26
   2    3   >4<   5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26
   2   >5<   2    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26
   2    5   >2<   5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26
   2    5    2   >5<   6    7    8    9   10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26
   2    5    2    5   >6<   7    8    9   10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26
   2    5    2   >7<   3    7    8    9   10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26
   2    5    2    7   >3<   7    8    9   10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26
   2    5    2    7    3   >7<   8    9   10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26
   2    5    2    7    3    7   >8<   9   10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26
   2    5    2    7    3   >9<   4    9   10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26
   2    5    2    7   >6<   3    4    9   10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26
   2    5    2   >9<   3    3    4    9   10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26
   2    5   >5<   3    3    3    4    9   10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26
   2    5    5   >3<   3    3    4    9   10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26
   2    5    5    3   >3<   3    4    9   10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26
   2    5    5    3    3   >3<   4    9   10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26
   2    5    5    3    3    3   >4<   9   10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26
   2    5    5    3    3   >5<   2    9   10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26
   2    5    5    3    3    5   >2<   9   10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26
   2    5    5    3    3    5    2   >9<  10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26
   2    5    5    3    3    5   >5<   3   10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26
   2    5    5    3    3    5    5   >3<  10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26
   2    5    5    3    3    5    5    3  >10<  11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26
   2    5    5    3    3    5    5   >5<   5   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26
   2    5    5    3    3    5    5    5   >5<  11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26
   2    5    5    3    3    5    5    5    5  >11<  12   13   14   15   16   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26
   2    5    5    3    3    5    5    5    5   11  >12<  13   14   15   16   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26
   2    5    5    3    3    5    5    5    5  >13<   6   13   14   15   16   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26
   2    5    5    3    3    5    5    5    5   13   >6<  13   14   15   16   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26
   2    5    5    3    3    5    5    5    5  >15<   3   13   14   15   16   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26
   2    5    5    3    3    5    5    5   >8<   5    3   13   14   15   16   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26
   2    5    5    3    3    5    5   >7<   4    5    3   13   14   15   16   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26
   2    5    5    3    3    5    5    7   >4<   5    3   13   14   15   16   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26
   2    5    5    3    3    5    5   >9<   2    5    3   13   14   15   16   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26
   2    5    5    3    3    5   >8<   3    2    5    3   13   14   15   16   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26
   2    5    5    3    3   >7<   4    3    2    5    3   13   14   15   16   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26
   2    5    5    3    3    7   >4<   3    2    5    3   13   14   15   16   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26
   2    5    5    3    3   >9<   2    3    2    5    3   13   14   15   16   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26
   2    5    5    3   >6<   3    2    3    2    5    3   13   14   15   16   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26
   2    5    5   >5<   3    3    2    3    2    5    3   13   14   15   16   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26
   2    5    5    5   >3<   3    2    3    2    5    3   13   14   15   16   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26
   2    5    5    5    3   >3<   2    3    2    5    3   13   14   15   16   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26
   2    5    5    5    3    3   >2<   3    2    5    3   13   14   15   16   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26
   2    5    5    5    3    3    2   >3<   2    5    3   13   14   15   16   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26
   2    5    5    5    3    3    2    3   >2<   5    3   13   14   15   16   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26
   2    5    5    5    3    3    2    3    2   >5<   3   13   14   15   16   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26
   2    5    5    5    3    3    2    3    2    5   >3<  13   14   15   16   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26
   2    5    5    5    3    3    2    3    2    5    3  >13<  14   15   16   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26
   2    5    5    5    3    3    2    3    2    5    3   13  >14<  15   16   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26
   2    5    5    5    3    3    2    3    2    5    3  >15<   7   15   16   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26
   2    5    5    5    3    3    2    3    2    5   >6<   5    7   15   16   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26
   2    5    5    5    3    3    2    3    2   >7<   3    5    7   15   16   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26
   2    5    5    5    3    3    2    3    2    7   >3<   5    7   15   16   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26
   2    5    5    5    3    3    2    3    2    7    3   >5<   7   15   16   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26
   2    5    5    5    3    3    2    3    2    7    3    5   >7<  15   16   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26
   2    5    5    5    3    3    2    3    2    7    3    5    7  >15<  16   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26
   2    5    5    5    3    3    2    3    2    7    3    5  >10<   5   16   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26
   2    5    5    5    3    3    2    3    2    7    3   >7<   5    5   16   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26
   2    5    5    5    3    3    2    3    2    7    3    7   >5<   5   16   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26
   2    5    5    5    3    3    2    3    2    7    3    7    5   >5<  16   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26
   2    5    5    5    3    3    2    3    2    7    3    7    5    5  >16<  17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26
   2    5    5    5    3    3    2    3    2    7    3    7    5   >7<   8   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26
   2    5    5    5    3    3    2    3    2    7    3    7    5    7   >8<  17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26
   2    5    5    5    3    3    2    3    2    7    3    7    5   >9<   4   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26
   2    5    5    5    3    3    2    3    2    7    3    7   >8<   3    4   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26
   2    5    5    5    3    3    2    3    2    7    3   >9<   4    3    4   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26
   2    5    5    5    3    3    2    3    2    7   >6<   3    4    3    4   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26
   2    5    5    5    3    3    2    3    2   >9<   3    3    4    3    4   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26
   2    5    5    5    3    3    2    3   >5<   3    3    3    4    3    4   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26
   2    5    5    5    3    3    2    3    5   >3<   3    3    4    3    4   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26
   2    5    5    5    3    3    2    3    5    3   >3<   3    4    3    4   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26
   2    5    5    5    3    3    2    3    5    3    3   >3<   4    3    4   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26
   2    5    5    5    3    3    2    3    5    3    3    3   >4<   3    4   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26
   2    5    5    5    3    3    2    3    5    3    3   >5<   2    3    4   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26
   2    5    5    5    3    3    2    3    5    3    3    5   >2<   3    4   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26
   2    5    5    5    3    3    2    3    5    3    3    5    2   >3<   4   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26
   2    5    5    5    3    3    2    3    5    3    3    5    2    3   >4<  17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26
   2    5    5    5    3    3    2    3    5    3    3    5    2   >5<   2   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26
   2    5    5    5    3    3    2    3    5    3    3    5    2    5   >2<  17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26
   2    5    5    5    3    3    2    3    5    3    3    5    2    5    2  >17<  18   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26
   2    5    5    5    3    3    2    3    5    3    3    5    2    5    2   17  >18<  19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26
   2    5    5    5    3    3    2    3    5    3    3    5    2    5    2  >19<   9   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26
   2    5    5    5    3    3    2    3    5    3    3    5    2    5    2   19   >9<  19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26
   2    5    5    5    3    3    2    3    5    3    3    5    2    5    2  >22<   3   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26
   2    5    5    5    3    3    2    3    5    3    3    5    2    5   >4<  11    3   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26
   2    5    5    5    3    3    2    3    5    3    3    5    2   >7<   2   11    3   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26
   2    5    5    5    3    3    2    3    5    3    3    5    2    7   >2<  11    3   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26
   2    5    5    5    3    3    2    3    5    3    3    5    2    7    2  >11<   3   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26
   2    5    5    5    3    3    2    3    5    3    3    5    2    7    2   11   >3<  19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26
   2    5    5    5    3    3    2    3    5    3    3    5    2    7    2   11    3  >19<  20   21   22   23   24   25   26
   2    5    5    5    3    3    2    3    5    3    3    5    2    7    2   11    3   19  >20<  21   22   23   24   25   26
   2    5    5    5    3    3    2    3    5    3    3    5    2    7    2   11    3  >21<  10   21   22   23   24   25   26
   2    5    5    5    3    3    2    3    5    3    3    5    2    7    2   11   >6<   7   10   21   22   23   24   25   26
   2    5    5    5    3    3    2    3    5    3    3    5    2    7    2  >13<   3    7   10   21   22   23   24   25   26
   2    5    5    5    3    3    2    3    5    3    3    5    2    7    2   13   >3<   7   10   21   22   23   24   25   26
   2    5    5    5    3    3    2    3    5    3    3    5    2    7    2   13    3   >7<  10   21   22   23   24   25   26
   2    5    5    5    3    3    2    3    5    3    3    5    2    7    2   13    3    7  >10<  21   22   23   24   25   26
   2    5    5    5    3    3    2    3    5    3    3    5    2    7    2   13    3   >9<   5   21   22   23   24   25   26
   2    5    5    5    3    3    2    3    5    3    3    5    2    7    2   13   >6<   3    5   21   22   23   24   25   26
   2    5    5    5    3    3    2    3    5    3    3    5    2    7    2  >15<   3    3    5   21   22   23   24   25   26
   2    5    5    5    3    3    2    3    5    3    3    5    2    7   >5<   5    3    3    5   21   22   23   24   25   26
   2    5    5    5    3    3    2    3    5    3    3    5    2    7    5   >5<   3    3    5   21   22   23   24   25   26
   2    5    5    5    3    3    2    3    5    3    3    5    2    7    5    5   >3<   3    5   21   22   23   24   25   26
   2    5    5    5    3    3    2    3    5    3    3    5    2    7    5    5    3   >3<   5   21   22   23   24   25   26
   2    5    5    5    3    3    2    3    5    3    3    5    2    7    5    5    3    3   >5<  21   22   23   24   25   26
   2    5    5    5    3    3    2    3    5    3    3    5    2    7    5    5    3    3    5  >21<  22   23   24   25   26
   2    5    5    5    3    3    2    3    5    3    3    5    2    7    5    5    3    3   >8<   7   22   23   24   25   26
   2    5    5    5    3    3    2    3    5    3    3    5    2    7    5    5    3   >5<   4    7   22   23   24   25   26
   2    5    5    5    3    3    2    3    5    3    3    5    2    7    5    5    3    5   >4<   7   22   23   24   25   26
   2    5    5    5    3    3    2    3    5    3    3    5    2    7    5    5    3   >7<   2    7   22   23   24   25   26
   2    5    5    5    3    3    2    3    5    3    3    5    2    7    5    5    3    7   >2<   7   22   23   24   25   26
   2    5    5    5    3    3    2    3    5    3    3    5    2    7    5    5    3    7    2   >7<  22   23   24   25   26
   2    5    5    5    3    3    2    3    5    3    3    5    2    7    5    5    3    7    2    7  >22<  23   24   25   26
   2    5    5    5    3    3    2    3    5    3    3    5    2    7    5    5    3    7    2   >9<  11   23   24   25   26
   2    5    5    5    3    3    2    3    5    3    3    5    2    7    5    5    3    7   >5<   3   11   23   24   25   26
   2    5    5    5    3    3    2    3    5    3    3    5    2    7    5    5    3    7    5   >3<  11   23   24   25   26
   2    5    5    5    3    3    2    3    5    3    3    5    2    7    5    5    3    7    5    3  >11<  23   24   25   26
   2    5    5    5    3    3    2    3    5    3    3    5    2    7    5    5    3    7    5    3   11  >23<  24   25   26
   2    5    5    5    3    3    2    3    5    3    3    5    2    7    5    5    3    7    5    3   11   23  >24<  25   26
   2    5    5    5    3    3    2    3    5    3    3    5    2    7    5    5    3    7    5    3   11  >25<  12   25   26
   2    5    5    5    3    3    2    3    5    3    3    5    2    7    5    5    3    7    5    3  >16<   5   12   25   26
   2    5    5    5    3    3    2    3    5    3    3    5    2    7    5    5    3    7    5   >5<   8    5   12   25   26
   2    5    5    5    3    3    2    3    5    3    3    5    2    7    5    5    3    7    5    5   >8<   5   12   25   26
   2    5    5    5    3    3    2    3    5    3    3    5    2    7    5    5    3    7    5   >7<   4    5   12   25   26
   2    5    5    5    3    3    2    3    5    3    3    5    2    7    5    5    3    7    5    7   >4<   5   12   25   26
   2    5    5    5    3    3    2    3    5    3    3    5    2    7    5    5    3    7    5   >9<   2    5   12   25   26
   2    5    5    5    3    3    2    3    5    3    3    5    2    7    5    5    3    7   >8<   3    2    5   12   25   26
   2    5    5    5    3    3    2    3    5    3    3    5    2    7    5    5    3   >9<   4    3    2    5   12   25   26
   2    5    5    5    3    3    2    3    5    3    3    5    2    7    5    5   >6<   3    4    3    2    5   12   25   26
   2    5    5    5    3    3    2    3    5    3    3    5    2    7    5   >7<   3    3    4    3    2    5   12   25   26
   2    5    5    5    3    3    2    3    5    3    3    5    2    7    5    7   >3<   3    4    3    2    5   12   25   26
   2    5    5    5    3    3    2    3    5    3    3    5    2    7    5    7    3   >3<   4    3    2    5   12   25   26
   2    5    5    5    3    3    2    3    5    3    3    5    2    7    5    7    3    3   >4<   3    2    5   12   25   26
   2    5    5    5    3    3    2    3    5    3    3    5    2    7    5    7    3   >5<   2    3    2    5   12   25   26
   2    5    5    5    3    3    2    3    5    3    3    5    2    7    5    7    3    5   >2<   3    2    5   12   25   26
   2    5    5    5    3    3    2    3    5    3    3    5    2    7    5    7    3    5    2   >3<   2    5   12   25   26
   2    5    5    5    3    3    2    3    5    3    3    5    2    7    5    7    3    5    2    3   >2<   5   12   25   26
   2    5    5    5    3    3    2    3    5    3    3    5    2    7    5    7    3    5    2    3    2   >5<  12   25   26
   2    5    5    5    3    3    2    3    5    3    3    5    2    7    5    7    3    5    2    3    2    5  >12<  25   26
   2    5    5    5    3    3    2    3    5    3    3    5    2    7    5    7    3    5    2    3    2   >7<   6   25   26
   2    5    5    5    3    3    2    3    5    3    3    5    2    7    5    7    3    5    2    3    2    7   >6<  25   26
   2    5    5    5    3    3    2    3    5    3    3    5    2    7    5    7    3    5    2    3    2   >9<   3   25   26
   2    5    5    5    3    3    2    3    5    3    3    5    2    7    5    7    3    5    2    3   >5<   3    3   25   26
   2    5    5    5    3    3    2    3    5    3    3    5    2    7    5    7    3    5    2    3    5   >3<   3   25   26
   2    5    5    5    3    3    2    3    5    3    3    5    2    7    5    7    3    5    2    3    5    3   >3<  25   26
   2    5    5    5    3    3    2    3    5    3    3    5    2    7    5    7    3    5    2    3    5    3    3  >25<  26
   2    5    5    5    3    3    2    3    5    3    3    5    2    7    5    7    3    5    2    3    5    3   >8<   5   26
   2    5    5    5    3    3    2    3    5    3    3    5    2    7    5    7    3    5    2    3    5   >5<   4    5   26
```

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth - 44 bytes

Straightforward procedural implementation.

```
K}2hhQVQJ@KZIP_J=hZ).?=GhPJ XKZ/JG=tZ XZKG;Z
```

[Test Suite](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=K%7D2hhQVQJ%40KZIP_J%3DhZ%29.%3F%3DGhPJ+XKZ%2FJG%3DtZ+XZKG%3BZ&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=0%0A10%0A47%0A4734%0A10000&debug=0).

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>158</s> <s>149</s> 133 bytes

This is a straightforward procedural implementation with one or two quirks to make sure the code works for all test cases. I use `[*range(2,n+9)]` to ensure that A is large enough (except for `n<3`, `n+9` is more than enough). The `else` clause divides the old `A[p]` by `d`, decrements `p`, and then adds `d` to the new `A[p]`, which is definitely bad coding practice. Otherwise, pretty straightforward. Golfing suggestions welcome!

**Edit:** -9 bytes without `sympy` thanks to Halvard Hummel. -14 bytes from Felipe Nardi Batista, -6 bytes from some cues from [Jonathan Frech's Python 2 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/144712/47581)

```python
p,_,*A=range(int(input())+2)
for _ in A:
 m=A[p];d=min(k for k in range(2,m+1)if m%k<1);p+=1
 if d<m:A[p-1]//=d;p-=2;A[p]+=d
print(p)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY9hC4IwEIa/71ccQrhLo2b0RbsP/o4QMTdr2OYwg/r1tilBB@O4vXvf5@Y@032wx7kdpKIoimaX1um2pLGxN8W1nfxxr4kjJhmybhihBm2hzBkYKi@uKiQZbXkPQeuDtlqz1CQCdQdm058FFi4hwcDP8mxyb9yJar8nWbgdZUUISkgyNwaiw9lvwuqFDARLZwtc/wFO6Jfw9Xv2aMxVNjk8p5FrXKQ1T6egrKQY4vVWvVXLw4eRsZ95hc3i8AU)

Comment: [145 bytes](https://tio.run/##TY7BCsIwEETv/Yr1ICS2Uqt4sHEP/Y7Sg5BEl5rtEiri18fkIDi3YWYeI5/1sfApJes8eMW6r2DAcRdvfHfq2HB90ZMRPFTwftDTAecCBBxGmYzFQKxm8EuEGYjhtwp1p8lD2M7XThveY2ekRosY8jgHdoOhL4i2RWuk5MXlSgXRra/IIKlQ6Y96Lt@yJBKvipp8l7ROXw)

Comment: [148 bytes](https://tio.run/##TU9BasNADLzrFcJQsqpTEjfkULs65B0hFDe7SYS98uK4tHm9s2tjqC5ipNHMKDyGW6e78dxZx1mWjcqigxENP4MhggMfX/tar868rzX/oBME3sLvTVqHWgJ6PhzDqbLsRU2Dl67HBkVxufF5QXJB/9J8FlTpGxeAEVtmX4Y8IdfeXZlENhu2VYiMKqGcLYQ@ZQk0xmDwNWVCxqkDJCv5Z7WnGCfWQmtr/23rEu9Db4Sm1awna3RqeYWreer@3Nmk/wlgOZ7NxmL7BA) by making it a full program

Comment: `if d-m:A[p]...` and `else:p+=1` to save a byte

Comment: [143 bytes](https://tio.run/##TY/RasMwDEXf9RUiUGotDa079tB4euh3lDCy2l1NasVkKW2/PnMSAtOLQNK99yi@@msr78O5tY6zLBuEvfTKS7z3igiOfHrravlxar@R/EAVRN7B4@pvDqUEDHw8xcpYDl5Ug5e2wwa94KIJuSZ/wbBqPjUZKVibmLMGTENbhDKpC11tt2xNLHhvRrecLcRuxIg0JCb4mnCQceoAY4r/l/JBiSTVcnarw7etS/ztO@VpWs1@foNOLK9xPU/d053V@DoBLOI5bNC7Pw) by removing the `else` statement

Comment: after removing the `else` statement, there is no difference in bytes to the function version

Comment: [139 bytes](https://tio.run/##TU/NasMwDL7rKURg1FoSOnfssHg69DlGKVnttiK1YrKMbU@fOQmF6SL49P0p/Y7XXp@nU@8DF0UxKYuORjR9jYYIUnWsHvc8tHoJRstXgu@r3AJqAxh5/54OznMUNR2e@wE7FMWVvKtiaUnOGB@6N0tOa7YulWwBM@jr2GR1bQ/bLXuXat652a1kD2mYKySach84LlWQcdkAc4r8S3mh3CTPnXZr44dvG/wcByO0nFY/qTCo5w1uVjT8hJOZ3yaAu3gNm@zTHw) by using unpacking in the creation of `p` and `A`

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>142</s> 127 bytes

- Saved fifteen bytes thanks to [Sherlock9](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/47581/sherlock9).

```python
T=range(2,input()+2);p=0
for _ in T:
 m=T[p];d=min(k for k in range(2,m+1)if m%k<1);p+=1
 if d<m:T[p-1]/=d;p-=2;T[p]+=d
print p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NczBCgIhFIXhvU9xN4FiQypEMM59C3cxRGBTIjoXcRY9vemi5eHnO/Stnz2b1hyWZ36/uDmHTEflQhphCRXb9gIPCBnczCChu9NqPaaQeYTR4mh/m6QWYYN0iovuXKJm0Ldf0tzhpNcLeksTGjt@JHpGJeQK1NpVKXX7AQ)

Comment: [127 bytes if you don't use `P(n)`](https://tio.run/##NcwxCgMhEIXh3lNME1DMkiikWXcKzxGWEDCbiDg7iFvk9EaLlI@f7/G3fnayrXksT3q/pD1H4qNKpa1yjFex7QUeEAn8LCCjv/PqAuZIMsFoabS/zdqouEE@pcV0rtEI6Dssee5wMusFg@MJrRs/GoPgEqkCt2ZvPw)

Comment: [126 bytes](https://tio.run/##NYxBDsIgEEX3nGLSxATExsJSOrfoznZhhCohTCcNJnp6xIV/95L3Pn/KcyNbK2EkfhWpxIT7jR5B2hMpwTiI8A73LuN05cV5zJFkgnXbIUEk@LtZGxVXyIc0GuVYo5mpsR/zpYW9Wc7oHfdo3e9Ho5@pO5LgPVIBrtUMbV8)

Comment: @FelipeNardiBatista Unfortunately, your suggestion doesn't seem to work for test cases `n<=4`

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, <s>118</s> 103 bytes

```
(s=Range[2,5^6];t=1;Do[If[PrimeQ@s[[t]],t++,s[[t]]/=(k=#2&@@ Divisors@s[[t]]);s[[t-1]]+=k;t--],#];t-1)&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n277X6PYNigxLz012kjHNM4s1rrE1tDaJT/aMy06oCgzNzXQoTg6uiQ2VqdEW1sHwtS31ci2VTZSc3BQcMksyyzOLyqGKtK0BtG6hrGx2rbZ1iW6urE6ykATdQ011f4DTcsrUXBIjzY0AILY//8B)

*Martin Ender saved 15 bytes*

Comment: You'd got a stray space in front of `Divisors`, you can use infix notation for `Do`, and you can just return `t` instead of `t-1` (1-based result).

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, 102+1 bytes

```php
for($a=range(2,$argn);$argn--;$d<$a[+$p]?$a[$p--]/=$d+!$a[$p]+=$d:$p++)for($d=1;$a[+$p]%++$d;);echo$p;
```

Run as pipe with `-R` or [try it online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/88803be4dbcb077244ae25147692b403a24ef301).

Empty output for input `0`; insert `+` after `echo` for a literal `0`

or use this 1-indexed version (103+1 bytes):

```php
for($a=range($p=1,$argn);$argn--;$d<$a[$p]?$a[$p--]/=$d+!$a[$p]+=$d:$p++)for($d=1;$a[$p]%++$d;);echo$p;
```

Answer (score 2):

## C (gcc), <s>152</s> 148 bytes

#### Minified

```c
int f(int n){int*A=malloc(++n*4),p=0,i,q;for(i=0;i<n;i++)A[i]=i+2;for(i=1;i<n;i++){for(q=2;A[p]%q;q++);if(A[p++]>q){A[--p]/=q;A[--p]+=q;}}return p;}
```

#### Formated with some comments

```c
int f(int n) {
  int *A = malloc(++n * 4), p = 0, i, q;
  // Initialize array A
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    A[i] = i + 2;
  // Do n step (remember n was incremented)
  for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {
    // Find smallest divisor
    for (q = 2; A[p] % q; q++)
      ;
    if (A[p++] > q) {
      A[--p] /= q;
      A[--p] += q;
    }
  }
  return p;
}
```

#### Main function for testing

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  if (argc != 2)
    return 2;
  int n = atoi(argv[1]);
  int p = f(n);
  printf("%d => %d\n", n, p);
  return 0;
}
```

#### For showing each step

1. Declare display() inside f()

   ```c
   int f(int n) {
     int *A = malloc(++n * 4), p = 0, i, q;
     void display(void) {
       for (int i=0; i < p; i++) {
         printf(" %d", A[i]);
       }
       printf(" \033[1;31m%d\033[m", A[p]);
       if (p+1 < n)
         printf(" %d", A[p+1]);
       printf("\n");
     }
     ...
   ```
2. Call display()

   ```c
     A[i] = i + 2;
   display();
   ```
3. Call display()

   ```c
     }
     display();
   }
   ```

Comment: You can [shave off some bytes](https://tio.run/##dY5RC4IwEMff/RTDCLamZSb0cC3wc9geSl0d1NrMnsTPbmdBEOTBdv/7/Y6xMj6X5TBDW16fVc12j7bC@/KyD37QFU8jC9C2zHC6BXyG2xEtF13AqFxDxPBwXh1sGBmeCNr6J9aTJttOm002/R7VKPvh@0FmRTe2vJDSLjIdOZVESMeDuTcccGcBpRR5gVqhTN8U1foruhF4lUJeOD334IkBGk6jlHrvRZcXcez0Snn4JEmp75u6fTaWOeiH4QU) by declaring A as an array and initializing your loop controls prior to the loops where possible, right?

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 123 bytes

A straightforward implementation. It is provided as a function, which takes the number of moves as input and returns the position p.

It loops over the sequence and moves the pointer forth and back according to the rules. The output is 0-based.

A note: in order to find the smallest prime factor of a number x, it computes the modulus of x relative to all integers from 0 to x. It then extracts the numbers with modulus equal to 0, which are always [0,1,...,x]. If the third such number is not x, then it is the smallest prime factor of x.

```r
p=function(l){w=0:l;v=w+1;j=1;for(i in w){y=v[j];x=w[!y%%w][3]
if(x%in%c(NA,y))j=j+1
else{v[j]=y/x;j=j-1;v[j]=v[j]+x}}
j-2}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY1BCsMgFET3OYUNCIoJje0u8he9QC9gXRSJoIgJaRqVkLPbpLMY5sEwMxePAPHuUJnAfINe7BiIp1uErvdihci4cMCFGWdikQ0o0i3DKp0SCaK8ZIyjkndVWUMStgFr8nw0mVIHjvFq8J9hO9uQr@kYci0XfzyNpX2vXHvbi34vpH6FupmO7@ZMtPwA)

Answer (score 1):

### Clojure, 185 bytes

```
#(loop[[n p][(vec(range 2 1e3))0]i %](if(= i 0)p(recur(if-let[q(first(for[i(range 2(n p)):when(=(mod(n p)i)0)]i))][(assoc n p(/(n p)q)(dec p)(+(n(dec p))q))(dec p)][n(inc p)])(dec i))))
```

Ouch, editing a "state" is not ideal in Clojure. You'll need to increase the exponent for larger inputs.

Comment: Why did you use pattern matching in the `loop`? You should be able to lose a few bytes without that.

Comment: Also, you might be able to change the `first` thing to a `some` statement.

Comment: Without pattern matching I had to repeat `recur` twice, one for each `if-let` branch. Also `(dec i)` would be duplicated. `some` needs a predicate, I could use `+` as we are dealing with numbers but this is one character longer than `first`. CMIIW

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8, <s>138</s> 135 bytes

```java
n->{int a[]=new int[++n],s=0,p=0,j=0;for(;j<n;a[j++]=j+1);for(;++s<n;p++)for(j=1;++j<a[p];)if(a[p]%j<1){a[p--]/=j;a[p--]+=j;}return p;}
```

**Explanation:**

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##VVHBbsMgDL3vK6xKk4JoukarNGmE/cF66THKgaWkgqUOAtppqvLtmSk5dAiD/TD2e2DVVZWj02iP33M3qBDgUxm8PQEYjNr3qtOwT@EdgK5IKzJByERGM0QVTQd7QJAwY/lxSymqaSXqn3Sp4RzbdZDbtSOzciv60RfC1ihUYzlvpeUVyyDngWDHOUuhlRUhtlaNawUzfZGcZ1tX7EZeWbYv0orscfImr@PFIzgxzSKTc5evgcgtHK@jOcKZ9BWH6A2emhYUy@JSu8TbED0wtazSRjTyKUDUIRbmrjsrX6Dd24It0evuMa62NB4fy3lzVVH/I5RLp95Lt8NviPq8GS9xQ/kYBywMX73DiuOGPoAtBaf5Dw)

```java
n->{                     // Method with integer as both parameter and return-type
  int a[]=new int[++n],  //  Integer-array with a length of `n+1`
      s=0,               //  Steps-counter (starting at 0)
      p=0,               //  Current position (starting at 0)
      j=0;               //  Index integer (starting at 0)
  for(;j<n;              //  Loop (1) from 0 to the input (inclusive due to `++n` above)
    a[j++]=j+1           //   And fill the array with 2 through `n+2`
  );                     //  End of loop (1)
  for(;++s<n;            //  Loop (2) `n` amount of steps:
      p++)               //    And after every iteration: increase position `p` by 1
    for(j=1;             //   Reset `j` to 1
        ++j<a[p];)       //   Inner loop (3) from 2 to `a[p]` (the current item)
      if(a[p]%j<1){      //    If the current item is divisible by `j`:
        a[p--]/=j;       //     Divide the current item by `j`
        a[p--]+=j;}      //     And increase the previous item by `j`
                         //     And set position `p` two steps back (with both `p--`)
                         //   End of inner loop (3) (implicit / single-line body)
                         //  End of loop (2) (implicit / single-line body)
  return p;              //  Return the resulting position `p`
}                        // End of method
```

Answer (score 1):

## Clojure, <s>198</s> <s>193</s> 191 bytes

This needs to be severely golfed...

```clj
#(loop[i(vec(range 2(+ % 9)))c 0 p 0](if(= % c)p(let[d(dec p)u(i p)f(some(fn[n](if(=(mod u n)0)n))(range 2(inc u)))e(= u f)](recur(if e i(assoc i d(+(i d)f)p(/ u f)))(inc c)(if e(inc p)d)))))
```

**Golf 1**: Saved 5 bytes by changing `(first(filter ...))` to `(some ...)`

**Golf 2**: Saved 2 bytes by changing `(zero? ...)` to `(= ... 0)`

---

### Usage:

```
(#(...) 10000) => 512
```

### Ungolfed code:

```clj
(defn prime-ant [n]
  (loop [counter 0
         pos 0
         items (vec (range 2 (+ n 9)))]
    (if (= n counter) pos
      (let [cur-item (nth items pos)
            prime-factor
            (some #(if (zero? (mod cur-item %)) %)
              (range 2 (inc cur-item)))
            equals? (= cur-item prime-factor)]
        (recur
          (inc counter)
          (if equals? (inc pos) (dec pos))
          (if equals? items
            (assoc items
              (dec pos) (+ (items (dec pos)) prime-factor)
              pos (/ cur-item prime-factor))))))))
```